# wildfly wont start because of new missing/unsatisfied dependencies

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, wildfly

When I try to start my **WildFly** server, I got this error :

```
2018-11-17 21:29:55,203 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
("subsystem" => "datasources"),
("jdbc-driver" => "org.postgresql")
]) - failure description: "WFLYJCA0041: Failed to load module for driver [org.postgresql]"
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
("subsystem" => "datasources"),
("data-source" => "swap")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
"jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/swap is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.org_postgresql]",
"jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/swap is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.org_postgresql]"
]}
2018-11-17 21:30:07,625 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
("subsystem" => "datasources"),
("data-source" => "swap")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
"jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/swap is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.org_postgresql]",
"jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/swap is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.org_postgresql]",
"jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/swap is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.org_postgresql]"
]}
```

And my **standalone.xml** :

```
<datasources>
     <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/swap" pool-name="swap" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/swap?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8</connection-url>
        <driver>org.postgresql</driver>
        <security>
            <user-name>postgres</user-name>
            <password>postgres</password>
        </security>
     </datasource>
     <drivers>
         <driver name="org.postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
             <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
             <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.Driver</xa-datasource-class>
         </driver>
     </drivers>
</datasources>
```

My PostgreSQL **module.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.postgresql">  
    <resources>  
        <resource-root path="postgresql-42.2.5.jar"/>  
    </resources> 
        <module name="javax.api"/>  
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>  
    </dependencies>  
</module>
```

What could be the problem? Please help and Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `module.xml` is invalid. A `<dependencies>` tag is missing. Try it with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.postgresql">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="postgresql-42.2.5.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

EDIT:

The `module.xml` file and the `postgresql-42.2.5.jar` have to be in

`C:\wildfly\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\modules\system\layers\base\org\postgresql\main`.

It is also recommended to put your modules directly into

`C:\wildfly\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\modules\`.

**So in your case `C:\wildfly\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\modules\org\postgresql\main`, that can be problem.**

For reference, also have a look at the [EAP7 Documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html/configuration_guide/datasource_management#example_postgresql_datasource) and you should also think about using the `jboss-cli`.

Comment: after editing the module.xml the problem stay the same. any other idea?

Comment: What is the location for your module.xml? Show me your directory ans file  layout

Comment: C:\wildfly\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\modules\system\layers\base\org\postgresql

Answer (score 0):

For configuration of PostgresSQL for WildFly server, you should follow the following steps.

**Step 1 : Adding PostgreSQL Module**

Create new folder `${wildfly_home}/modules/system/layers/base/org/postgresql/main/` if not exist.

Download Latest Driver Jar via this link => https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html and put under the above folder.

Also in that new folder, Create `module.xml` and put the following config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.postgresql">

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="postgresql-42.2.23.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
            
</module>
```

May be jar version need to update in `resource-root`.

**Step 2 : Update DB configs from `standalone.xml`**

Remove Existing **`<driver>`** config and add new config as follow.

```
<driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
    <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
</driver>
```

Remove existing **`<datasource>`** config and add new config as follow.

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/PostgresDS" pool-name="PostgresDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/swap?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8</connection-url>
    <driver>postgresql</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>postgres</user-name>
        <password>postgres</password>
    </security>
    <pool>
        <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
    </pool>
</datasource>
```

Modify `default-bindings` datasource name to **`PostgresDS`** from **`ExampleDS`**.

```
<default-bindings context-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" datasource="java:jboss/datasources/PostgresDS" ...
```

Make sure that you have created your `swap` database in PostgreSQL database server.

Now, run server and it will be fine.